# Automatically add keys to ssh agent in Mac OS without keeping passphrase in keychain

Tags: macos, ssh, ssh-keys

In Ubuntu, the default behavior is that the ssh client offers all keys present in ~/.ssh/ directory and when it finds a matching key it asks for its passphrase. The key remains unlocked in memory and I need to enter the password again if I reboot.

How can I get the same behavior in Mac OS?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ssh-add
```

on the command line. It will keep your key(s) open until your mac goes to sleep, the screen gets locked, you logout or reboot. See

```
man ssh-add
```

for more use cases.

Comment: Thank you very much, however I was looking for an automated way of adding all keys in ~/.ssh. ssh-add doesn't do that. Also I prefer it to run automatically. I am also kinda curious how it worked out of the box in linux.